# jQuery resize() for showing and hiding an image

Tags: jquery

I must make a simple site using jQuery for hiding or showing a picture in function of the size of the window, like on a phone, in landscape or portrait. Every time the window changes in size it shows or hides a picture.

my problem is : the big picture and my `<p>` are not hidden when my width is bigger than my height  , and when it return to  `width < heigth` it doesn't show back my little picture.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var height = $(window).height();
  var width = $(window).width();

  if (width > height) {
    // Landscape
    $("#landscape").css('display', 'none');
    $("#image").show(); ///show a big picture
    $("#pimage").hide();
    $("#p1").hide();
  } else {
    // Portrait
    $("#landscape").css('display', 'block');
    $("#landscape").hide(function() {
      $("#image").hide();
      $("#pimage").show(); ///show a little picture
      $("#p1").show(); ///show a <p>
    });
  }
}).resize();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width = device - width , initial - scale =1.0">
    <title>site de knapen arnaud</title>
</head>
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a  href="index.html"> aceuille</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="orientation.html"> orientation</a></li>
                <li><a  href="cacher_montrer.html">cacher et montrer</a></li>
            </ul>
            
    </nav>  
</header>


<body>
<img id="image" src="../img/paysage.jpg"> /// my big pic
<img id="pimage" src="../img/p_paysage.jpg"> /// my little pic 
<p id="p1">veuiller passez en paysage</p>


 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You provided an overview of what your code should do but haven't explained what is wrong or what your actual question is.

Comment: When you edit, add backticks around code `

Comment: You have `$(#landscape").css("display", "block")` then immediately `$("#landscape").hide()` - I image one of those should be #portrait?

Comment: Please include some relevant HTML so we can see what you're trying to hide and when.